# Justify the given locus

Tags: geometry

[image]

---

> Let $\square ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral, and $\overline{\rm CD}=2$. $N$ is the midpoint of $\overline{\rm DB}$. Determine the locus of $N$ when $D$ moves.

What I know is that the locus is the circumference shown(centre F, radius 1), but I don't know **why**.

Comment: `when D moves` Suppose $D$ ends up lying on $BC$ while it moves. Where would $A$ be then, so that $ABCD$ is a `convex quadrilateral`? There need be some additional constraints on the "*movement*" of $\,D\,$, otherwise the answer is undetermined. See my longer version of it posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let F’ be the midpoint of BC. We further let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two different locations of D. Correspondingly, we have $N_1$ and $N_2$ as the midpoints.

[image]

Note that $CD_1 = CD_2$. By midpoint theorem, $N_1F’ = (\frac 12)CD_1 = (\frac 12)CD_2 = N_2F’$.

This means F’ is the center of the circle passing through $N_1$ and $N_2$ with radius = half of $CD$.

Answer (score -1):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

That's an oddly worded question, either carelessly or perhaps deliberately so.

At face value, point $\,A\,$ doesn't figure anywhere, so the quick answer is to take the [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) centered at $\,B\,$ with ratio $\,1/2\,$ which sends $\,D\,$ to $\,N\,$ and $\,C\,$ to the midpoint $\,F\,$ of $\,BC\,$, determine that $\,NF = CD /2 = 1\,$, then conclude that the locus is the circle of radius $\,1\,$ centered at $\,F\,$.

It is certainly true that the locus is a *subset* of that circle, but on the other hand the problem also states that the quadrilateral $\,ABCD\,$ is convex, and $\,D\,$ "*moves*". This could be interpreted either as the other three vertices staying put in place, or as the side lengths staying constant with $\,B,C\,$ fixed and $\,A\,$ moving along with $\,D\,$ like in an articulated mechanism. Each interpretation would lead to different answers as to what arcs of the full circle satisfy the condition, neither entirely trivial.

Otherwise put, *not enough information* for a definitive answer.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.